# How do I update the base URL for Twilio SHA-2 update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

How do I update the Base URL that Twilio uses for the SHA-2 update? I don't see any place to do this. We use the Twilio Rest using .Net CSharp code. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Megan from Twilio here.

You can check your setup against this endpoint: api.twilio.com:8443. If a test command to that endpoint succeeds, then you should not be required to make any changes.

If your command fails, [I would recommend following the instructions here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-api-security-certificate-change-on-december-1-2015). An example in C# (be sure to update your Account SID, Auth Token, the From Phone Number and the To Number):

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient(
    "[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]",
    "[YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]",
    "[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]",
    "2010-04-01",
    "https://api.twilio.com:8443/");

var result = client.SendMessage("[FROM_PHONE_NUMBER]", "[TO_PHONE_NUMBER]", "Your system is ready for the upcoming change to the Twilio API's SSL certificate. No further action is needed");
```

If the above fails:

Outside of syntax errors, most likely your SSL libraries need to be updated. There is an SSL library on your server, and by the way it is not exactly the same thing as a Twilio helper library that you are probably using. You'll need to make sure your SSL library is up to date by December. If you are using a cloud provider, they can help confirm. If you are hosting yourself, your IT should check - if it is OpenSSL, for example, you should see if you can get it up to date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Megan that command gives me error as The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/https://api.twilio.com:8443//SMS/Messages.json was not found

Comment: I've just updated with some more information regarding what might be happening given an error. If you continue to experience an issue, I would suggest writing in to help@twilio.com.